# Matlab Symbolic Toolbox Syntax Error

Tags: matlab

I have symbolic math toolbox installed in my Matlab. However, when I type in the standard A = sym('A', dim) [also noted in mathworks site] code it gives an error. Why is that so ?

> > A = sym('A', [2 4])
> >
> > ??? Error using ==> error
> >     Formatted arguments cannot be non-scalar numeric matrices.
> >
> > Error in ==> sym.sym>assumptions at 2180
> >         error('symbolic:sym:sym:errmsg1','Second argument %s not recognized.',a);
> >
> > Error in ==> sym.sym>tomupad at 2148
> >             assumptions(S,x,a);
> >
> > Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.sym at 114
> >                 S.s = tomupad(x,a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an older version of Matlab.

The documentation is for R2012b.

In my R2010a version, the documentation does not show this capability.

Comment: Yeah I have R2009b but symbolic toolbox version is 5.3. I think I have to update my Matlab